# What's the correct flow of injecting Appsettings.json from a main application and how to do it

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have my main .net core application called **AppOne**. In its appsettings.json I define which api's it should be able to call. For example:

```
"ApiSettings": {
"UrlToCall": "http://test",
}
```

Then there is my intermediate and shared project library, called **InfraApp** that makes the call itself to the Api.
There might be a second app called **AppTwo** where the url is different.
Both **AppOne** and **AppTwo** reference the **InfraApp** since the logic is common and call the code in there to make the actual call. However the settings (that specifies which url to call) are specific to the api's themselves and therefore cannot be specified in the **InfraApp**.

Let's consider only **AppOne** so far.
Such settings are registered through the Options pattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.0) into the startup.cs:

```
services.AddOptions();
var apiSettings = Configuration.GetSection("ApiSettings");
services.Configure<ApiSettings>(apiSettings);
```

and I have my ApiSettings class:

```
public class ApiSettings
{
    public string UrlToCall { get; set; }
}
```

what is the correct way to pass such ApiSettings to the **InfraApp** ? **InfraApp** doesn't know anything about ApiSettings since this is defined in the **AppOne**. Should I defined the **ApiSettings** class into the **InfraApp**? IMHO sounds wrong because it is something specific about the **AppOne** api but maybe I am thinking in the wrong way. Thanks!

Comment: You need to review your design choices. Current explanation is still unclear. How does `InfraApp` expect to consume run-time settings details?

Comment: No I agree with you, I just need to understand which is the right way of injecting settings in a non strongly typed way from a project to another

Comment: Without more details about your design, answering that would be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you have something like this:

```
    public interface IApiSettings
        {
            string UrlToCall { get; set; }
        }
        public class ApiSettings:IApiSettings
        {
            public string UrlToCall { get; set; }
            public ApiSettings()
            {
                    ...
                Console.WriteLine($"ApiSettings");
                        ...
            }
        }

        public class IInfraApp{}

        public class InfraApp : IInfraApp
        {
            private IApiSettings _ApiSettings;
            //using Microsoft.Extensions.Options:
            public InfraApp(IOptions<ApiSettings> settings)
            {
                _ApiSettings = (IApiSettings)settings.Value;
                Console.WriteLine($"InfraApp {_ApiSettings.UrlToCall}");
            }
        }
```

then, you can add/register, something along these lines:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddControllers();
            ...
            ...
            //
            services.Configure<ApiSettings>(Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<IInfraApp, InfraApp>();
            ...
            ...
            //get instance of infraapp:
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var infraapp = provider.GetService<IInfraApp>();
            //
            ...
            ...
    }
```